# How to limit x-axis of 3D animated mesh in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, animation, 3d, limit, mesh

I have an animated 3D mesh of a sine wave, but i want to limit all my axis to specific ranges.

Here is a piece my code:

```
[x,t] = meshgrid(x,t);
j=1;
while 1
j=j+1;
y = a*sind(2*pi*f*(j/100+(x*T)/wl));
mesh(y);
F(j) = getframe;
end
movie(F);
```

*the values of the variables a,f,T and wl are predefined by the user*

i want to limit the x-axis from 10 to 20, can someone show me how to do it?

Comment: At first use mesh(x,t,y) that will depend from real values of x and t (mesh(y) depend from indices in x,t arrays). Than set x range from 10 to 20 in generation time.

Answer (score 0):

Call [xlim](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) after you draw the mesh.

```
xlim([10 20])
```